# C++ How to pass lambda [&]() as an argument for void (*draw)()

Tags: c++

I have a method which takes a void function as an argument. Like so,

```cpp
void update(void (*draw)());
```

inside `main` how will I pass a lambda which could take an out-scope variable to be passed to `update`?

it works if I do it like this

```cpp
Player player(20, 20);
void drawFace(){
    player.draw();
}

int main() {
    myClass.update(drawFace);
}
```

the problem having such code above is that it only works if `Player` is defined as global variable. How will I pass a lambda instead so `Player` can be declared inside main. I want something like this

```cpp
int main() {
    Player player(20, 20);
    myClass.update([&](){
        player.draw();
    });
}
```

Comment: Capturing lambdas can't be converted to equivalent function pointers. There is no room in a function pointer to also encode the capture information. Your `draw` callback needs some argument to which you can communicate extra information (in this case, which `player`). If `player` is indeed a global object, then don't capture it. You don't need to, it's global.

Comment: thanks for answering @FrançoisAndrieux, do you have other suggestion on how will I achieve this btw? so that I can pass a function but at the same time I can use outer scope variable from main. Can you suggest me a pattern to make this possible?

Comment: You could template your parameter or change it to `std::function<void()>`.  Either of those choices would accept both lambdas and function pointers.

Comment: Is the signature of the `update` function under your control or is it a third party library?

Comment: I am  using my own `update` function. no third library in building it.

Comment: waw, great to know this @DrewDormann , it works now using `std::function<void()>`. thank you so much. It basically solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `std::function<void()>` in declaring the argument solves the problem.

instead of defining `update`

```cpp
    void update(void (*draw)());
```

Use it like this solves the issue

```cpp
    void update(std::function<void()>draw);
```

Now I can pass either function or lambda to it and both will works out of the box.
Works!

```cpp
Player player(20, 20);
void drawFace(){
    player.draw();
}

int main() {
    myClass.update(drawFace);
}
```

or
Also works now!

```cpp
int main() {
    Player player(20, 20);
    myClass.update([&](){
        player.draw();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lambdas have their own compiler-generated type.
You can use a template definition with a concept to limit the type.

```
template <typename T>
concept Block = requires(T&& t) {
    { voidF(); } -> std::same_as<void>;
};

template <typename T>
requires Block<T>
void update(T&& draw) {
  // implementation
}
```

This will also avoid the overhead added by `std::function`.

Comment: Note that concepts were introduced in C++20. For earlier versions, a simply template with a Callable parameter will suffice: `template <typename T> void update(T draw) { draw(); }` You can use SFINAE via `std::enable_if` and `std::is_invocable` if you want to restrict the type of `T`